# Save multiple images and multiple plots into one page pdf file using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have 2 images files and .csv file that I'll be creating a plot. However, I couldn't figure out how to save two images and a plot in the same page.

from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages is what I have been using and I don't have much experience in python. The results are came out as multiple pages instead of one page.

Comment: You probably want to create subplots (2 subplots).  That way you have a single figure (one page) but two "regions" that you can control independently.  You can do this with `fig.add_subplot( ... )` or using `gridspec` if you want the two plots to be different sizes (or generally for more flexibility with subplots).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.